# Suppress response from WebSocket API lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a websocket API with lambda integration which returns a response body as expected for e.g:

```js
{statusCode: 200, body: "test me"}
```

The problem is that when I do *not* want to send any response to an incoming message the websocket sends an empty message to the client.

I have tried every conceivable combination of `200` vs `204` and body of `null`,`undefined` or `""` but every time an empty message goes out to the client.

How can I signal to the API not to send an empty message when no response is required?

Thanks.